# Using Git, if some commits are lost, how to view it or get it back?

Tags: git

While experimenting with Git, I changed a file's content from `1` to `100`, and was able to commit and see it in the log.  But after some more test and

```
git checkout <some_hash>      // I think this is to revert the whole repo to a 
                              //     certain state

git checkout master           // And this is to change the repo to the most 
                              //     current state
```

the commit histories were lost in `git log`.  What happened -- could the commit have gone into another branch and how to view it or get it back?

Comment: Try `git blame -Llinenum,linenum soucefile` does that show it

Comment: @AdrianCornish it won't show still... `git reflog` indeed shows it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly where the commit went without knowing exactly what you did. However, the `git reflog` command will show the positions that the current branch head has been in the past, including commits that may no longer be in the history.

Comment: yes, the commit will show using `git reflog`, and the line and the one before it are:  `d3fb496 HEAD@{11}: commit: version 100`
and `6726b65 HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from f1f06d8291ef90e53440... to 6726b...` and then if I use `git checkout f1f0`, then `git log` will show the commit.  (by the way, is there a way to see all the branches and commits in a text graph or image graph.  Maybe that will show too?)

Comment: @動靜能量: You may find `git show-branch` and `gitk` useful; there are also other tools that show the Git branch tree. However, most of show only branches that are "reachable", that is they have names of some kind (a head, a tag, etc). It is possible to have commits that can be found only by knowing the commit id (as it sounds like you might have here).

Comment: interesting, if `git show-branch`, I only see 1 branch, so what is the "branch" of `git checkout f1f0`?  Because when I do that, I see commit that I don't see otherwise

Comment: There's a good explanation of this situation at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head You can find other descriptions of the situation by searching for "detached head". It's basically a branch that doesn't have a name yet.